# Understanding function written for STM32

Tags: c, stm32, led

I'm new to embedded programming at all. I'm doing one example with others friends, so they have written some parts that I don't understand. In this example we have to program game 'space invaders' on led matrix 16x16

```
int setLED(int line, int column, enum command_e cmd)
{
    return (line<<5)|(column<<2)|cmd;
}
```

before that we defined in header:

```
enum command_e{
    LED_STAY = 0x00,
    LED_ON   = 0x01,
    LED_OFF  = 0x02,
    LED_TOGGLE = 0x03
};
```

Any help would be welcomed.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is use of this function in main.

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void){
static int count = 1;
static int line=0;
static int column=0;
panel_t send;
send.led0 = 0;
send.led1 = 0;
send.led2 = 0;
send.led3 = 0;

if(count == 1)
    GPIOA->ODR = 1<<15;
else if(count == 2){
    GPIOA->ODR = 0<<15;
    busyFlag = 0;
} else if(count == 50){
    send.led0 = (field[line+8][column].counterMAX > 0) ? setLED(line, column, LED_ON) : setLED(line, column, LED_OFF);
    send.led1 = (field[line][column].counterMAX > 0) ? setLED(line, column, LED_ON) : setLED(line, column, LED_OFF);
    if(line != 0)
        send.led2 = (field[line][column+8].counterMAX > 0) ? setLED(line, column, LED_ON) : setLED(line, column, LED_OFF);
    else{
        send.led2 = (leben < (8 - column)) ? setLED(line, column, LED_OFF) : setLED(line, column, LED_ON);
    }
    
    send.led3 = (field[line+8][column+8].counterMAX > 0) ? setLED(line, column, LED_ON) : setLED(line, column, LED_OFF);
    received = sendData(send); //received global variable to update field in main
    if(column < 7){
        column++;
    }
    else{
        column=0;
        (line < 7) ? (line++) : (line = 0);
    }
}

if(count == 120)
    count = 0;
count++;

TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update);
```

}

Comment: There's nothing specific to the architecture or to embedded programming here.  Function `setLED()` performs some relatively simple arithmetic on its arguments and returns the result.  Look up the operators involved (`<<` and `|`) in a reference or tutorial if you don't know what they do.  Go through a tutorial or textbook on C if you don't understand (C's flavor of) `enum`s.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an actual question here, did it get removed?

Comment: I rolled this question back because without its content it was meaningless noise.

Answer (score 0):

This function is simply returning an int with the value of the binary combination of line rotated 5 times to the left, column rotated 2 times to the left and the command (which have the values defined in the enum)

So, if you do:

test = setLED( 3 , 2 , LED_TOGGLE)

test will be equal to: ( ( 00000011 << 5) | (00000010 << 2) | 00000011 )

which will give:

```
01100000 OR
00001000 OR
00000011
--------
01101011
```

The rest of the logic is dependent of the rest of the code

Comment: But why they rotate it 5 and 2 times? I have tried with changing numbers but my game isn't working correctly, leds are blinking only.

Comment: This is dependent on the rest of your code, this function is not really setting any led, it's just returning a combination of the input variables, I sugest you study the rest of the code and see how this is applied

Comment: @Alena Everdeen it is not rotated. It is shifted. This makes a huge difference. And why. To code position and command in one chunk of data. But this function will not work anyway. To code number from zero to 15 you need 4 bits. So the actual code shold be: (line<<6)|(collumn<<2)|cmd and after this first 2 bits contain cmd, next four column and next four line

Comment: leds are blinking only:  Are you calling with  LED_TOGGLE?  If so, that is expected.  Otherwise we can't see enough of the code to help you.

Comment: Well, I have structure that has LED_TOGGLE and it's given value. I have worked with 6 but in this game lights should move you know in blocks and when I write 6 they are just blinking and now creating normal blocks that will move. @JustinJ.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the small amount of code posted here:

settLED() isn’t doing anything to actually set an LED.  It looks to me like it is used to create one value which is a combination of address (row/column) and desired state.  This will probably then be written to a control register.

If you are wondering about `return (line<<5)|(column<<2)|cmd;`, it might be helpful to split it up so you can step through and watch what happens:

```
int setLED(int line, int column, enum command_e cmd)
{
   int result = (line << 5);
   result = result | (column << 2);
   result = result | cmd;

   return result;
}
```

Result of `setLED(1, 1, LED_ON);`

```
result = (line << 5);              // result -> 0x20
result = result | (column << 2);  // result -> 0x24
result = result | cmd;             // result -> 0x25
```

**EDIT**:

Possible register bit definition based on values given (states 0-3 and 16x16 matrix)

```
// Bits:  15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
// Field:                    RRRRRRRRRR  CCCCCCCCCC  SSSS
// Range of Values:          0-15        0-15        0-3
```

**EDIT**:
OK, based on a 6-bit address and the fact you are limiting the line and column to a max of 7:

```
if(column < 7){
    column++;
}
else{
    column=0;
    (line < 7) ? (line++) : (line = 0);
}
```

It looks like you are using an 8x8 LED matrix, which can be addressed with 6 bits (3 for line, 3 for column).  I’ve updated my “register description” which should make it clear where the shift by 2 and 5 come from.

```
// Bits:    7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
// Field:   RRRRRRR  CCCCCCC  SSSS
// Range:   0-7      0-7      0-3
```

Each quadrant of your 16x16 matrix is one of these 8x8 matrices written to with the following commands:

```
send.led0 = ...;
send.led1 = ...;
send.led2 = ...;
send.led3 = ...;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that part, but I don't understand why this numbers (5 and 2)...

Comment: It is probably specified in the datasheet for whatever part you are programming.  Look for a description of the register and you will probably see something like: Bits 0-1 specify state.  Bits 2–5 specify column, Bits 6-9 specify row.  It takes 4 bits (0x0 to 0xA) to address the row and 4 bits to address the column of the 16x16 display.  Double check the 2 and 5 against the datasheet.  There may be a bug in your function.

Comment: The upper 6 bits indicate for each module the address of the LEDs in question, the lower 2 bits contain the data again. But it didn't work when I put 6...

Comment: @AlenaEverdeen I answered your other question too, but it was deleted before I finished.  There was important information there too.